# Visual Studio displayed lots of errors, but there is only one actual error

Tags: c#, wpf, compiler-errors

I have a custom control library in my solution, where my main WPF project references it. If there is an error in the custom control library, then the error list goes mental and displayed hundreds of errors. Here is an example of one such incident.

[image: Error List]

Now this is just an error that I **forced** in order to demonstrate the problem.

In this case, the problem isn't so severe, as there are *only* 21 errors. However, there have been occasions where I have had to filter though hundreds of errors to find the **actual** error that's causing everything else to fail.

I believe I *understand* what the problem actually is. I think the problem is due to the custom control library **not being built**, therefore my main project can't find the dll for it, and therefore the custom controls cannot be found, which causes the errors.

Now, in truth, the error list isn't *lying*, I mean, these are *real* errors. However, that being said, is there a way to prevent this from occurring?

Comment: You could sort by file errors to look for only that ones that are in your file, then look all them in line order.

Comment: I've often wondered about the same question myself. In a really big solution, with multiple projects, this can be really annoying. Good question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, I think that this extension will help you as it stops the build as soon as an error occurs.

[StopOnFirstBuildError](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/91aaa139-5d3c-43a7-b39f-369196a84fa5/)

Comment: Thank you. This does seem to do the trick in my case. Great find!